# MBP freezes when I print

Tags: preview, printing, performance

My MBP13 Retina freezes when I print a file from Preview. I can continue to use the computer on other softwares but Preview is freezing...

I have 4 network's printer and one unplugged USB printer.

Do you have any idea for solving this trouble?

Partia Preview's log (hang log):

```
Date/Time:       2015-02-02 09:58:23 +0100
OS Version:      10.10.2 (Build 14C109)
Architecture:    x86_64h
Report Version:  21

Command:         Preview
Path:            /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
Version:         8.0 (859.7)
Build Version:   1
Project Name:    Preview
Source Version:  859007000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             3442

Event:           hang
Duration:        1.00s (process was unresponsive for 62 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           11 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro11,1
Active cpus:     4

Fan speed:       1495 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  11  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff899145c9]
  11  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 10772) [0x7fff8c91aa14]
  11  -[NSApplication run] + 711 (AppKit + 95752) [0x7fff8c92f608]
  11  ??? (Preview + 12289) [0x10e16b001]
  11  -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 3937 (AppKit + 1618779) [0x7fff8caa335b]
  11  -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 920 (AppKit + 2129845) [0x7fff8cb1ffb5]
  11  -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 359 (AppKit + 2144797) [0x7fff8cb23a1d]
  11  _os_activity_initiate + 75 (libsystem_trace.dylib + 3287) [0x7fff8bbdacd7]
  11  -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 114 (AppKit + 2148828) [0x7fff8cb249dc]
  11  -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 382 (AppKit + 2149566) [0x7fff8cb24cbe]
  11  -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452 (AppKit + 2042737) [0x7fff8cb0ab71]
  11  _os_activity_initiate + 75 (libsystem_trace.dylib + 3287) [0x7fff8bbdacd7]
  11  -[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:] + 621 (AppKit + 5950123) [0x7fff8cec4aab]
  11  __91-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke + 55 (AppKit + 5950193) [0x7fff8cec4af1]
  11  __91-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke388 + 149 (AppKit + 5950720) [0x7fff8cec4d00]
  11  -[NSPrintPanel beginSheetWithPrintInfo:modalForWindow:delegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:] + 514 (AppKit + 5959662) [0x7fff8cec6fee]
  11  -[NSWindowController window] + 110 (AppKit + 2412050) [0x7fff8cb64e12]
  11  -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 586 (AppKit + 2514439) [0x7fff8cb7de07]
  11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 92154) [0x114d3f7fa]
  11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 93330) [0x114d3fc92]
  11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 69598) [0x114d39fde]
  11  -[PKBrowser start] + 79 (PrintingPrivate + 18044) [0x7fff863bc67c]
  11  -[PKBrowser(private) startBrowsingForNearbyDevices] + 27 (PrintingPrivate + 18727) [0x7fff863bc927]
  11  -[PKBrowser(Bonjour) startBonjourBrowser] + 440 (PrintingPrivate + 23227) [0x7fff863bdabb]
  11  DNSServiceBrowse + 219 (libsystem_dnssd.dylib + 16588) [0x7fff833e50cc]
  11  __select_nocancel + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 91154) [0x7fff8bb91412]
 *11  ??? (kernel + 6142240) [0xffffff80007db920]


Process:         Preview [3442]
Path:            /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [1]
UID:             501
Sudden Term:     Dirty
Task size:       32000 pages
Note:            Unresponsive for 62 seconds before sampling

  Thread 0x1c1c4      DispatchQueue 1     11 samples (1-11)   priority 46
  <thread QoS user interactive, boosted, received importance donation from WindowServer [3346], IO policy important>
  11  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff899145c9] 1-11
    11  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 10772) [0x7fff8c91aa14] 1-11
      11  -[NSApplication run] + 711 (AppKit + 95752) [0x7fff8c92f608] 1-11
        11  ??? (Preview + 12289) [0x10e16b001] 1-11
          11  -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 3937 (AppKit + 1618779) [0x7fff8caa335b] 1-11
            11  -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 920 (AppKit + 2129845) [0x7fff8cb1ffb5] 1-11
              11  -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 359 (AppKit + 2144797) [0x7fff8cb23a1d] 1-11
                11  _os_activity_initiate + 75 (libsystem_trace.dylib + 3287) [0x7fff8bbdacd7] 1-11
                  11  -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 114 (AppKit + 2148828) [0x7fff8cb249dc] 1-11
                    11  -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 382 (AppKit + 2149566) [0x7fff8cb24cbe] 1-11
                      11  -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452 (AppKit + 2042737) [0x7fff8cb0ab71] 1-11
                        11  _os_activity_initiate + 75 (libsystem_trace.dylib + 3287) [0x7fff8bbdacd7] 1-11
                          11  -[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:] + 621 (AppKit + 5950123) [0x7fff8cec4aab] 1-11
                            11  __91-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke + 55 (AppKit + 5950193) [0x7fff8cec4af1] 1-11
                              11  __91-[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke388 + 149 (AppKit + 5950720) [0x7fff8cec4d00] 1-11
                                11  -[NSPrintPanel beginSheetWithPrintInfo:modalForWindow:delegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:] + 514 (AppKit + 5959662) [0x7fff8cec6fee] 1-11
                                  11  -[NSWindowController window] + 110 (AppKit + 2412050) [0x7fff8cb64e12] 1-11
                                    11  -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 586 (AppKit + 2514439) [0x7fff8cb7de07] 1-11
                                      11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 92154) [0x114d3f7fa] 1-11
                                        11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 93330) [0x114d3fc92] 1-11
                                          11  ??? (<ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21> + 69598) [0x114d39fde] 1-11
                                            11  -[PKBrowser start] + 79 (PrintingPrivate + 18044) [0x7fff863bc67c] 1-11
                                              11  -[PKBrowser(private) startBrowsingForNearbyDevices] + 27 (PrintingPrivate + 18727) [0x7fff863bc927] 1-11
                                                11  -[PKBrowser(Bonjour) startBonjourBrowser] + 440 (PrintingPrivate + 23227) [0x7fff863bdabb] 1-11
                                                  11  DNSServiceBrowse + 219 (libsystem_dnssd.dylib + 16588) [0x7fff833e50cc] 1-11
                                                    11  __select_nocancel + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 91154) [0x7fff8bb91412] 1-11
                                                     *11  ??? (kernel + 6142240) [0xffffff80007db920] 1-11

  Thread 0x1c1d2      DispatchQueue 2     11 samples (1-11)   priority 46
  <thread QoS user interactive, boosted, received importance donation from WindowServer [3346], IO policy important>
  11  _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52 (libdispatch.dylib + 19050) [0x7fff8d46ba6a] 1-11
    11  kevent64 + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 94770) [0x7fff8bb92232] 1-11
     *11  ??? (kernel + 5988368) [0xffffff80007b6010] 1-11

  Thread 0x1c1f9      11 samples (1-11)   priority 46
  <thread QoS user interactive, boosted, received importance donation from WindowServer [3346], IO policy important>
  11  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 5149) [0x7fff8292f41d] 1-11
    11  _pthread_start + 176 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12773) [0x7fff829311e5] 1-11
      11  _pthread_body + 131 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12904) [0x7fff82931268] 1-11
        11  _NSEventThread + 137 (AppKit + 1602363) [0x7fff8ca9f33b] 1-11
          11  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 (CoreFoundation + 464984) [0x7fff90213858] 1-11
            11  __CFRunLoopRun + 1371 (CoreFoundation + 466939) [0x7fff90213ffb] 1-11
              11  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 (CoreFoundation + 469812) [0x7fff90214b34] 1-11
                11  mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 70878) [0x7fff8bb8c4de] 1-11
                 *11  ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (kernel + 1165472) [0xffffff800031c8a0] 1-11

  Thread 0x1cb19      11 samples (1-11)   priority 54
  <boosted, received importance donation from WindowServer [3346], IO policy important>
  11  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 5149) [0x7fff8292f41d] 1-11
    11  _pthread_start + 176 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12773) [0x7fff829311e5] 1-11
      11  _pthread_body + 131 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12904) [0x7fff82931268] 1-11
        11  startIOThread(void*) + 147 (CoreVideo + 8859) [0x7fff8239529b] 1-11
          11  CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 676 (CoreVideo + 9560) [0x7fff82395558] 1-11
            11  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 90422) [0x7fff8bb91136] 1-11
             *11  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 26908) [0xffffff7f80efd91c] 1-11

  Binary Images:
         0x10e168000 -        0x10e32afff  com.apple.Preview 8.0 (859.7)                                  <487D571B-251B-39C4-8437-6313EB83D12C>  /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
         0x114d29000 -                ???  ???                                                            <ABBA6E84-68DE-3AED-8CCC-ACF36D221A21>
      0x7fff82393000 -     0x7fff823c0fff  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.8 (145.1)                                <18DB07E0-B927-3260-A234-636F298D1917>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
      0x7fff8292e000 -     0x7fff82937fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1)                             <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
      0x7fff833e1000 -     0x7fff833e9fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1)                                <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
      0x7fff863b8000 -     0x7fff863dffff  com.apple.printingprivate.framework.PrintingPrivate 10.0 (148) <1EFBB095-7BA4-3D4C-8532-25989C0A0279>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintingPrivate.framework/Versions/A/PrintingPrivate
      0x7fff89911000 -     0x7fff89914fff  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1)                                        <4E33E416-F1D8-3598-B8CC-6863E2ECD0E6>  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
      0x7fff8bb7b000 -     0x7fff8bb98fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.10.72)                            <97CD7ACD-EA0C-3434-BEFC-FCD013D6BB73>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
      0x7fff8bbda000 -     0x7fff8bbe0fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.1.3)                                 <A9E6B7D8-C327-3742-AC54-86C94218B1DF>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
      0x7fff8c918000 -     0x7fff8d462fff  com.apple.AppKit 6.9 (1344.72)                                 <44EF7DEB-3072-3515-9F34-2857D557E828>  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
      0x7fff8d467000 -     0x7fff8d491fff  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4)                                    <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0>  /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
      0x7fff901a2000 -     0x7fff90538fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.9 (1152)                            <CBD1591C-405E-376E-87E9-B264610EBF49>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 *0xffffff7f80ef7000 - 0xffffff7f80efffff  com.apple.kec.pthread 1.0 (1)                                  <8365956C-8613-3ED4-BC64-0D8570D2089F>  /System/Library/Extensions/pthread.kext/Contents/MacOS/pthread
 *0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80009fffff  kernel (2782.10.72)                                            <DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5>  /System/Library/Kernels/kernel
```

NB:

- MPB13 Retina mid-2014
- OSX 10.10.1
- Preview 8.0 (859)

NB: Same problem when I have no install printer (so I can't print in PDF...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** the firewall app `HandsOff` blocked DNS requests even if I desactivated it. I uninstalled it and now it's works fine.